# Organizing photos and folders in Google Photos using Google Drive

Tags: google-drive, google-photos

I know this question has been asked before, but under a slightly different context. There have been a few technology changes since then, so I'm hoping there is now an answer to this question.

Basically, I have my photo collection organized into folders and sub folders like this:

\2015
\2015\date-event_name1
\2015\date-event_name2

\2014\
\2014\date-event_name3

and so on.

If you use the Google Photos uploader, it removes all of the folders, kills the event name from the folder, and just uploads all photos into a giant lump.

Recently, Google added a 'Google Photos' folder to Google Drive. It would be ideal if I could just link the folders from my photo collection to this folder. The idea is to preserve my dates and event names and have Google Photos create albums for each gallery.

When I try this, the photos never make it to Google Photos. The only time the photos appear in google photos is if I remove all of the folders and just dump the pictures into the root folder.

Is there any way around this to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: Check this thread http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/78842/how-to-upload-existing-albums-to-new-2015-google-photos.

Comment: I did see that, thanks. I didn't know if there was a way to achieve this now that Google Drive had a link to Google Photos.

Comment: To my knowledge only one service has this feature: Apple Photos, existent on Apple iPhone, OS X and has a web interface on icloud.com.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it, but first need to upload all photos in Google photos. When you have it uploaded, enter in Google Drive, inside the photos folder and reorganize in subfolders your photos.

The photos won't be removed in photos, but you can synchronize to your computer with your structure.